# Adjusting only the width of a picture

Tags: python, image, height, width, image-resizing

Say an image with size `(width = 200, height = 250)`

I want to change the size to `(width = 400, height = 250)`

How would that be possible without giving the error "IndexError: image index out of range"?

Comment: Well, if really want to do that, the image will look funky tho.

Comment: And what have you tried so far

Comment: You can try using this python library, but as above resizing could make the image weird https://pypi.org/project/python-resize-image/

Comment: You can use PIL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `PIL`:

```
from PIL import Image
im=Image.open(filename)
im2=im.resize((400,250))
im2.save(filename)
```

If currently, saves as new image, but if want to display it, do:

```
im2.show()
```

Easy as that.

`PIL.Image.resize` does it.

Related:

> See the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html)
>
> > See the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) about this

Note for second argument, which has a default parameter (`0`), it's using `NearestNeighbors`, if you set it to `1` it's `LANCZOS`, if you set it to `2` it's `BILINEAR`, if you set it to `3` it's `BICUBIC`

So see what you like the most :-)

Comment: thanks, it is great!  do you know the algorithm with the im.resize((400,250))?

Comment: @MaJun Edited mine

Answer (score 0):

Try these code

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread("image.jpg")
resize=cv2.resizes(img,(400,250))
cv2.imshow("Image",resize)
```